# Protein-Bound Drugs in Kwashiorkor

Tags: pharmacokinetics

Kwashiorkor is characterised by decreased serum protein (including serum albumin) due to poor dietary protein intake.

What is the effect of this lowered serum protein on highly-protein-bound drugs? Is it substantial enough that administering such drugs (such as warfarin, though it's hard to imagine a situation in which a patient with kwashiorkor would need anticoagulant therapy) is potentially dangerous, and if so, can this be compensated for?